# How to automatically rotate turrets towards enemy direction continously?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, angle, autorotate

I have a turret placed as a game-object ,i have set the target as enemy in inspector,but somehow the turrets just point towards my enemy but are not continuously rotating on z axis.what is the problem,any help thanx...!!

Here is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TurretScript: MonoBehaviour
{ 
public Transform target;

void Update()
{

    Vector3 tarPos = new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y, 10);
    Vector3 lookPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(tarPos);
    lookPos = lookPos - transform.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookPos.y, lookPos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);

}
}
```

Comment: You might want to post this in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/, they're focused on both game development in general, and Unity-specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve this? Cheat!  Something like this:

```
public class TurretScript: MonoBehaviour
{ 
    //values that will be set in the Inspector
    public Transform Target;
    public float RotationSpeed;

    void Update()
    {
        var direction = Target.transform.position - transform.position;

        // Set Y the same to make the rotations turret-like:
        direction.y = transform.position.y; 

        var rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction, Vector3.up);      
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(
                                         transform.rotation, 
                                         rot, 
                                         RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is rotating but not rotating circular,wanted the y and x axis to be constant.

Comment: itz aint rotating at all :(

Comment: Did you set RotationSpeed? If not, you're rotating at a speed of zero. Don't forget to set Target, too.

Comment: i have set the rotation speed as 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66458/discussion-between-safwan-and-steve-lillis).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Transform.LookAt() from the [Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)

I find this to be the simplest approach without the headache of computing rotations.